# How to use the exact Opencv C++ functions in EMGU?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, emgucv

As mentioned in the EMGU documentations ".Net wrapper to the OpenCV image processing library"

We depended on the functions we could find online but we really didn't figure out how to use those exact OPENCV C++ functions in the opencv documentations like blob?

How to use them in the EMGU platform?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking in the EmguCV source code for the OpenCV functions you are looking for and see how they are wrapped. It is all there.

There is also the need to move data between the managed side and the unmanaged side.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

EmguCV provides a class called [CvInvoke](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/bb544594-4bf7-5a11-594c-f143b226f1da.htm) which wraps a lot of the basic opencv functionality. The previous link goes for the EmguCV 3.4.3 documentation. Maybe you need another version. Anyway I recommend to also check other classes aside from CvInvoke. The API documentation should be a good starting point.